# Cloudformation create encrypted athena glue table

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-athena, aws-glue

I have a CF template to create a glue table which reads from S3 CSV files.

```
MyTableEncrypted:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Table
    Properties:
      DatabaseName:
        Ref: MyDatabase
      CatalogId:
        Ref: AWS::AccountId
      TableInput:
        Name:
          Fn::Sub: "my-table-encrypted"
        Parameters: { "classification" : "csv" }
        StorageDescriptor:
          Location:
            Fn::Sub: "s3://my-encrypted-bucket/"
          InputFormat: "org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat"
          OutputFormat: "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat"
          SerdeInfo:
            Parameters: { "separatorChar" : "\t" }
            SerializationLibrary: "org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde"
          StoredAsSubDirectories: false
          Columns:
            - Name: first_name
              Type: string
            - Name: last_name
              Type: string
```

I want to add `TBLPROPERTIES {has_encrypted_data : false}` to this table. How to achieve this in CF Template ?

No hint about encryption property in documentation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/webapi/API_StorageDescriptor.html

Answer (score 4):

Appending `has_encrypted_data` to TableInput Parameters worked.

```
MyTableEncrypted:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Table
    Properties:
      DatabaseName:
        Ref: MyDatabase
      CatalogId:
        Ref: AWS::AccountId
      TableInput:
        Name:
          Fn::Sub: "my-table-encrypted"
        Parameters: { "classification" : "csv", "has_encrypted_data" : "true" }
        StorageDescriptor:
          Location:
            Fn::Sub: "s3://my-encrypted-bucket/"
          InputFormat: "org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat"
          OutputFormat: "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat"
          SerdeInfo:
            Parameters: { "separatorChar" : "\t" }
            SerializationLibrary: "org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde"
          StoredAsSubDirectories: false
          Columns:
            - Name: first_name
              Type: string
            - Name: last_name
              Type: string
```